# Building with 10.14 SDK - but DTSDKName value in Info.plist is macosx10.7

Tags: xcode, macos, sdk, notarize

I just ran into a weird issue when attempting to notarize one of my apps...

I build the app with the current macOS SDK (that is, 10.14).

However, in the final app, DTSDKName value in Info.plist is **macosx10.7** (instead of macosx10.14).

Therefore, I can't notarize the app as it requires at least the 10.9 SDK.

I don't have this issue with other apps.

I do have a temporary solution - to build the app with 10.10 SDK which I also have installed in Xcode. In this case, the DTSDKName is correct: macosx10.10.

I submitted this bug to Apple.

I also guess I can just insert the desired value into Info.plist with a script in a Build Phase - but it's sure not the way it's supposed to work.

I wonder if anyone has any idea what's going on?

Thanks for any info,
Leo

macOS 10.14.5
Xcode 10.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got to the bottom of it...

I had OS X 10.7 SDK installed with Xcode. Yes I know it's not officially supported - but I used to need it for some legacy projects (but not anymore).

Removing the 10.7 SDK solved the issue.